# Simple java parallel program

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

To get familiar with parallel programming I wanted to make a simple java parallel program that calculates the sum of all the elements of an Array by using 4 threads.

**Here is the SumClass that extends Thread class:**

```
public class SumThread extends Thread {
int lo;
int ho;
int Arr[];
int ans=0;

//constructor
SumThread(int Arr[], int lo, int ho){
    this.Arr = Arr;
    this.lo = lo;
    this.ho = ho;
}

public void run(){
    for (int i=lo; i<ho; i++){
        ans += Arr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

**And here we have the main class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int Arr[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 5, 2, 4 };
    int ans = 0;

    SumThread[] sum = new SumThread[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sum[i] = new SumThread(Arr, (i * Arr.length) / 4, Arr.length * ((i + 1) / 4));
        sum[i].start();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        try {
            sum[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ans += sum[i].ans;
    }

    System.out.println(ans);

  }

}
```

I used the join() function to wait for the Threads to finish before accessing the ans values and printing it.
The point is that I get 11 as result, and that is totally wrong. I noticed that it sums only the final 3 values (5,2,4). It seems that only the fourth Thread gets started.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int ans = IntStream.of(Arr).sum();`

Comment: What do you think `(i + 1) / 4` will give you? For `i` = 1 or 2 it's 0, and for 3 and 4 it's 1.

Comment: Thanks it was really a stupid mistake. Obviously you are right, I cannot use integer in that part! Thank you a lot! It works now!

Comment: You should just add a print in your ctor to find that the threads are getting main lo:0ho:0
main lo:3ho:0
main lo:6ho:0
main lo:9ho:12

Comment: But you are immediately calling join after start. You should call a general function from threads when they finish (in a synchronzed way) and then if all executed this function, it can call join or whatever result point you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thread safety is how you pass the data around. You could use an ExecutorService and at least the return value passed via a Future would be thread safe, however I would use one of the built in streams API and it could replace all this code with 2-3 lines.

```
int[] array = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 5, 2, 4 };
int sum = IntStream.of(array).parallel().sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

or

```
System.out.println(IntStream.of(1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 5, 2, 4).parallel().sum());
```

Comment: I don't need the program actually, I know that there are way better ways to do this kind of work. But as I wrote in the post, I'm trying to get familiar with parallel programming, and figuring out what's wrong in my program so that I can solve it. Hope you understood.

Comment: @Ergo in that case, you need to ensure that the results are being read in the main thread. I suggest you print them out or use your debugger to see what the values are.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you 51.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int Arr[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 5, 2, 4 };
    int ans = 0;

    SumThread[] sum = new SumThread[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sum[i] = new SumThread(Arr, (i * Arr.length) / 4, (Arr.length * (i + 1))/ 4);
        sum[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        try {
            sum[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ans += sum[i].ans;
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

}